# How to make gf behave like :drop

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

When I'm in a python file and I go to the imports, put the cursor on one of them, and type `gf`, it opens the corresponding file in a new buffer in the same window, even if the file is already open in another tab/split.

Is there any way to make it behave like the `:drop` command, i.e., to make it go to the window in which the file is already open instead of editing it in the current window? Ideally, it would default to opening the file in a new tab if the file is not already open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be the other `gf` commands: `<C-w>f` opens in a new split and `<C-w>gf` in a new tab.

You could try to `:set switchbuf=useopen` and see if that helps.

Lastly, you could use an ftplugin to map `gf` to `:drop` as follows:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
nnoremap <buffer> gf :execute 'drop' expand('<cfile>')<CR>
```

(If you go for this route, you may want to adjust `b:undo_ftplugin` as well.)

This last solution does suffer from the fact that `:drop` does not open in a new tab if the buffer doesn't exist (it uses the current window). You could fix this with

```
nnoremap <buffer> gf :execute (bufloaded(expand('<cfile>')) ? 'drop' : 'tabedit') expand('<cfile>')<CR>
```

There are further caveats to either mapping solution:

- `expand('<cfile>')` should be an exact replica of the filename-resolution system used by `gf`, which is far more intelligent than just "word under cursor" (it involves using `include`/`includeexpr` and `suffixesadd`, at the least). If `expand('<cfile>')` isn't working, you can try `.'.py'` or `.&l:suffixesadd` as a workaround.
- I made the mappings buffer-local since I put them in an ftplugin. In general I recommend not overriding vim’s builtins unless it’s strictly a superset of the behavior, but YMMV.
- If you consider tab pages to be more like window layouts, it may be more advantageous to envision a workflow where you are ok with having the same file open in multiple windows across multiple tab pages. I may have a tab for the main entry points of a project, a tab for each of successive stages of a processing pipeline, etc. Each of those tabs may have different or the same files; sometimes, I have the same file in multiple windows just for different views! This depends on the complexity of the project though, as for many projects I don't need more than 2 or 3 windows and am often only in 1 or 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a couple of things to add. I had originally thought that the second nnoremap for gf would not work, because the imports don't have .py extensions, but the corresponding file does, so the command would edit a new file instead of the correct existing one. But the help page for suffixesadd seems to indicate that it's the right option. How might I add that to the mapping you provided?

Comment: Another thing, I tried out the mapping you provided, to see if I could figure out myself how to integrate the suffixesadd option, but the mapping gives the following error when invoked: E492: Not an editor command: tabopen *file* (replacing file with the name of the import that the cursor was on prior to invoking the mapping).

Comment: @ThaddaeusMarkle crud, it’s tabedit. Edited. (Obviously I don’t use tabs much.) as for suffixesadd, you just need to make sure it’s set for the python filetype (using setlocal). It may already be set, which you can check by opening a python file and running `:setlocal suffixesadd?`

Comment: It is, I had already checked before commenting. Now that the error is fixed (I do use tabs, so I should have seen it already...), I'll try it myself, and if I run into any problems, I'll comment here again. Thanks again!

Comment: Here's the finished mapping: `nnoremap <silent><buffer> gf :execute (bufloaded(expand('<cfile>' . '.py')) ? 'drop' : 'tabedit') expand('<cfile>') . '.py'<CR>`. You'll notice that I just concatenated '.py' onto the strings instead of the contents of the &suffixesadd option, mainly because I know that this is only for python and the extension will only ever by '.py'. Also, I added <silent> as I always do for mappings that run a command (faster and less visual noise). I will accept your answer, and I would appreciate it if you would edit it to include the new mapping, just for posterity's sake.

Comment: Hey OP, just wanted to let you know that I generally leave things like `<silent>` off in my answers (unless they are specifically about `<silent>`!)—it's simply the most general form, and future readers may not understand why it's there without explanation that would detract from the rest of the answer. Advanced users are more than welcome to and usually comfortable enough modifying code they take from the internet :) At any rate, this explains why your edit was rejected on one level; on another, code-level edits are generally not ideal

Comment: @Ben that makes sense. Thank you, I really appreciate that you bothered to explain that. Many people wouldn't have! I know that I as a reader to an answer like that would have added `<silent>` on my own (in fact, that's exactly what I did...) ;-). However, I'm not sure I understand why "code-level edits" are not ideal. Could you explain that?

Comment: @ThaddaeusMarkle youre welcome! [this meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246) is a good starting point. We’re not bound by meta.so (we have our own meta and can make our own policies), but I haven’t heard good reasons to change this one yet. Personally, I think code edits can often be addressed with a quick comment or a new answer, and most of the code edits I’ve seen do change *something*. I’ve had pushback before when the change concerned correcting a typo in the code, which I rejected and left a note for the OP to fix their code...

Comment: ...I’m not sure there’s really a consensus policy yet overall. Might be worth starting a meta on it to get the community to decide.

Comment: Just wanted to add something else: The reason that I didn't use &l:suffixesadd is that it is normally a comma-separated list, so if that were the case it would append, for example '.py,.pyc', if that was what suffixesadd was set to, which would result in an error. I could be wrong about this, and if I am, please correct me ;-).

Comment: @ThaddaeusMarkle you’re correct; `split(&l:suffixesadd, ',')[0]` gets closer, but they’re all fallible. That’s why I don’t really recommend the mapping :)